# find files with two types of extensions last modified over 30 days ago

Tags: shell, find

I want to find all the files in a directory that have not been modified for at least 30 days and end in `.xml` or `.out`.  This is my attempt to cobble together a couple of references to build the right `find` syntax:

```
find . -mtime +30 -type f / (-name "*.xml -o -name "*.out" ) / -print
```

I'm getting

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

What am I missing in my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there! This works:

```
find . -mtime +30 -type f \( -name \*.xml -o -name \*.out \)
```

Your `/ (` becomes `\(` (an escaped open parenthesis; as you discovered the shell treats `(` specially so it needs to be escaped with `\`); likewise `) /` should actually be `\)`. The names need `*` to match anything ending with the given extension, and that also needs to be escaped, so `".xml"` (I added the missing closing quote) becomes either `\*.xml` or `"*.xml"`.

Finally `-print` can be dropped since that's `find`'s default action.